Alternative to .getValues to paste the contents of a row to another sheet and retain the hyperlinks
I'm using the code below to move a row from one tab to another when the status field states 'complete'. The issue I'm encountering is that the data is being paste as values, when one of the fields is a hyperlink that we'd like to retain. The code is working as intended with the exception of the hyperlinks being copied across as values. I'm new to Javascript, but from looking at the code I assume it's because of the use of '.getValues'. Is there something I can change it to to retain the hyperlinks when they're moved across?
function script1(e) {
  // Define the source and destination sheets 
  var sourceSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Request Form");
  var destinationSheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Closed Requests");
  
  // Define the column where the status is located
  var statusColumn = 31; // Change to the actual column number (3 is column C).

  // Get the edited range
  var editedRange = e.range;
  var editedRow = editedRange.getRow();
  console.log(editedRow);
  // Check if the edited column is the status column
  
  if (editedRange.getColumn() === statusColumn) {
    // Get the status value
    var status = editedRange.getValue();
    if (status === "Complete") { // Change "Complete" to the status that triggers the move
      // Copy the entire row to the destination sheet
      var lastColumn = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();
      var sourceData = sourceSheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues();

      if (sourceData[0].length > 0) { // Check if the source data is not empty
        destinationSheet.appendRow(sourceData[0]);
        }
      
      // Delete the row from the source sheet
      sourceSheet.deleteRow(editedRow);
      console.log("The row is moved from Request Form to Closed Requests")
    }
  }
  else{
    console.log(" under the else and the code didn't execute");
  }
  }


range.copyTo is one option.

To do what @TheMaster recommended, remove .getValues() on var sourceData as well as change sourceData[0].length > 0 to sourceData[0] != "" and destinationSheet.appendRow(sourceData[0]); to sourceData.copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
